# Any one else having trouble with the WordPress TwentyTen theme is not adding current-menu-item to all of my pages in the menu?

Tags: wordpress, twenty-ten-theme

Ok, so I'm using the new TwentyTen theme and getting familiar with it. From what I understand you create a custom menu and picks it's spot, which was done with no problem. The menu consists of all of my top level pages, but only one page gets the current-menu-item class added to it's list item when you're on that one page. The rest of the pages do not get assigned this class.

Strange isn't it? All of the pages are top level, no children, and I've viewed the source code rendered on all of them and no current-menu-item.

Is any one else having this problem? Just an FYI, this is a local install on MAMP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. If you're adding your own static pages to a new menu than you need to add them using the "Pages" box and not the "Custom Link" box. Props to [@jakemgold](http://twitter.com/jakemgold) for the ah-ha moment!

Comment: I was trying to drum up an answer, but admittedly haven't spent enough time with custom menus yet - glad you solved it :)

Comment: It's all good! Thanks for taking the time to look though! I should have *known* better and not done it bass ackwards, like I did. ;-)